# Dynamically add Button to Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding a RadButton dynamically to a Panel. So I am creating the button as so:

```
        RadButton btnAwesome = new RadButton();
        btnAwesome.AutoPostBack = true;
        btnAwesome.Text = "Click me...";
        btnAwesome.ID = "LinkButtonTest";
        btnAwesome.Click += new System.EventHandler(lnkbtnEditRecord_Click);
```

and it it should call this method onclick:

```
    protected void lnkbtnEditRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        salesEditPanel.Visible = true;
        resultPanel.Visible = false;
        zipPanel.Visible = false;
        ddlPanel.Visible = false;
        topPanel.Visible = false;
    }
```

It adds the button the Panel but it doesn't add the onclick to it. Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: are you asking about binding of click event?? is it not raising on click of button???

Comment: whats is the RadButton? a button? or a radiobutton?

Comment: @Mr. , He is using Telerik controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is due to how postbacks work - Each time a page is requested (postback or not), the control instances are created. Once the controls are created and other page properties set, the viewstate is parsed to set the control's properties.  Then events are created and dispatched.

The important thing here is, this instance of "page" is not the same instance that you generated before - it's a new one and the ASP.NET webforms engine has set all the properties for you *as if* it were the same.   But on this instance, you haven't created your `btnAwesome`, so there's nothing there to send a "click event" from or to!

In order to change this, you need to make sure that by the end of Page_Load, all of the controls you want to fire events have been created.   So you must recreate btnAwesome and add it to the panel before returning from Page_Load if you want it to fire the click event.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run that code to initialize the button on every postback, and you will need to ensure that it's run sufficiently early in the page's lifecycle.  Which page event is that code in, and will it be run on each successive postback?